# 4 digit decimal to 16 bit binary conversion code

Tags: c, pointers, bit-manipulation

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  char str[17];
  getBin(3334, str);
  printf("%s\n", str);
  return 0;
}

void getBin(int num, char *str)
{
  *(str+16) = '\0';
  int mask = 0x8000 << 1;
  while(mask >>= 1)
    *str++ = !!(mask & num) + '0';
}
```

I don't really understand how the while loop functions. Could someone explain in simple terms what it's doing? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, sure. So the `0x8000` = 8 * 16^3 = 2^15 . Now if you shift that to the left one more time, you get 2^16.

The while loop continously takes mask through all the values:

- 2^15
- 2^14
- 2^13
  ...

So the while loop considers mask as an iterator for the powers of two in a regular integer.

Now what does `!!(mask & num)` do ? It returns 1 if the bit indicated by mask is flipped `on` or 0 if it's `off`.

The expression  `!!(mask & num)` returns 0 or 1 and added to the character code of `0` it returns the character code for `0` or for `1`.

So for example if `num=12` and `mask=4` then `!!(4 & 12)  =  !!(100 & 1100) = !!(100)= !0 = 1`. Now, if you add `1 + '0'` what do you get? You get `1+48=49` which is the character code for `1`.

The `*str++ = ..` assigns the value to that particular position in the string, and then increments the pointer to point to the next character.

The question is: Is `str` null-terminated or not?

I think the line `*(str+16) = '\0';` takes care of the null-termination, because it preventively sets a null termination byte.

So I guess this is an explanation to the piece of code you wrote above.

Comment: Also note that the code would crash and burn on an 8 or 16-bit computer, where int is 16 bits.

Comment: Good to know. Anyone have a better way if it was running on a 16 bit micro like the MSP430?

Answer (score 1):

```
void getBin(int num, char *str)
```

`getBin()` takes a number (`num`) and a string to write to (`str`)

```
  *(str+16) = '\0';
```

The last character of `str` is set to a NULL terminator

```
  int mask = 0x8000 << 1;
```

We create a variable called `mask` and set it to 0x8000 left shifted by 1, which is 0x10000. Why? might be easier to see in binary:

0x8000<sub>16</sub> => 1000 0000 0000 0000<sub>2</sub> (then move everything left 1 place)

                      1 0000 0000 0000 0000<sub>2</sub> => 0x10000<sub>16</sub>

```
  while(mask >>= 1)
```

While the `mask` is greater than 0, we shift right 1 bit, and save the result back to `mask`. (the `>>=` means shift right and save). That means the values will be:

> 0x10000<sub>16</sub> == 1 000 0000 0000 0000<sub>2</sub> == 65536<sub>10</sub>
>   
> 0x8000<sub>16</sub> == 1000 0000 0000 0000<sub>2</sub> == 32768<sub>10</sub>
>   
> 0x4000<sub>16</sub> == 100 0000 0000 0000<sub>2</sub> == 16384<sub>10</sub>
>   
> 0x2000<sub>16</sub> == 10 0000 0000 0000<sub>2</sub> == 8192<sub>10</sub>
>   
> ...
>   
> 0x4<sub>16</sub> == 100<sub>2</sub> == 4<sub>10</sub>
>   
> 0x2<sub>16</sub> == 10<sub>2</sub> == 2<sub>10</sub>
>   
> 0x1<sub>16</sub> == 1<sub>2</sub> == 1<sub>10</sub>

Finally on each of these iterations:

```
    *str++ = !!(mask & num) + '0';
```

This code is taking each digit in `num`, AND'ing it with the 1 bit which is set in `mask` and checking to see if the result is `== 0` then it's adding the value of the character `0` and storing that final ASCII "number" into the string, then incrementing the string.

Let's break that down one step at a time:

```
mask & num // num is 3334    = 0011 0011 0011 0100
           // mask starts at = 1000 0000 0000 0000
```

So on the first iteration the value of `(mask & num)` is `0`.

`!!(x)` is the same as saying: `(x == 0 ? 0 : 1)` so on the first iteration we have a `0` so `!!(0)` gives us 0, we want to store that into our string, but we want it to be an ascii character. The ASCII character for 0 is 0x30<sub>16</sub> so we add 0x30 to 0 and get 0x30 (or `'0'`) then

```
*str++ = '0';
```

We dereference `str` and store the character 0, then we have a post increment moving to the next character in the string.